# URLs to remove cannot find the urls entered

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-admin-center

I try to use the SharePoint Admin > Search > Remove Search Results
I add a link to a page (modern page) to remove that from index. The page is deleted already, but I want it to stop showing up in my search-based roll ups.
https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[site]/subsite/SitePages/MyPage.aspx

But I always get: The above URLs marked with an asterisk were not found.

I know it physically does not exist, but it is present in search index (e.g. I can find it with REST api: _api/search/query...) and I thought that was the purpose of the removal...

I have also tried to force refresh of page library and even site, without luck (I suspect that is ignored in SharePoint Online?)

Answer (score 0):

Since the page is deleted, it might the reason that go the error message “The above URLs marked with an asterisk were not found.”

As for the deleted item appears in the search index, try to go to site settings->Search-> Search and Offline Availability, click Reindex site, wait for some time to execute crawl in SharePoint Online background, then check if the deleted page appear in the search index.